# How to fix "OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'" when 'en' is already downloaded + models are valid

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I'm attempting to load 'en' for spacy in a jupyter notebook but I am encountering the following error. I have followed the steps presented in previous threads but to no avail.

The commands run successfully from terminal, however modifications to jupyter's sys.path and sys.executable have not succeeded either. I'm using python3.7.

I'm fairly new to jupyter / python so I appreciate any & all advice.

I have included lines 3 and 4 as this was suggested by various other answers on this site, however the same error persists as below:

```
1. import spacy
2. import sys
3. !python3 -m spacy validate
4. !python3 -m spacy download en
5. nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

When I replace line 5 with:
    `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`
I get the same issue found in https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3102, however the solution there is to validate as in LINE3 (which appears to be fine).

This is the output of lines 3, 4 and 5, showing that the model is valid, it is downloaded, yet the error still persists

LINE3 output:

```
✔ Loaded compatibility table

====================== Installed models (spaCy v2.1.4) ======================
ℹ spaCy installation:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy-2.1.4-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/spacy

TYPE      NAME             MODEL            VERSION                            
package   en-core-web-sm   en_core_web_sm   2.1.0   ✔
link      en               en_core_web_sm   2.1.0   ✔
```

LINE4 and LINE5 output:

```
    Requirement already satisfied: en_core_web_sm==2.1.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.1.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.1.0)
    You are using pip version 19.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    ✔ Download and installation successful
    You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    ✔ Linking successful
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/en_core_web_sm
-->
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy-2.1.4-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/spacy/data/en
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-89c4b06ef071> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('python3 -m spacy download en')
----> 2 spacy.load('en')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in load(name, **overrides)
     25     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
     26         deprecation_warning(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path))
---> 27     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     28 
     29 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model(name, **overrides)
    134     elif hasattr(name, "exists"):  # Path or Path-like to model data
    135         return load_model_from_path(name, **overrides)
--> 136     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
    137 
    138 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Thanks!

Comment: stop the kernal and the server and run the jupyter notebook again.